# Can I add Observer inside Observer? I actually tried but inner observers not working properly. Sometimes one of them work, sometimes no one work

Tags: android, observable, android-livedata, observer-pattern

I used Android Architecture Components (ViewModel, LiveData) and used Room to fetch data from Local Sqlite Database using Repository. Outermost observer just fine, problem is only with inner observers.

See the Code:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        BranchDetailsViewModel branchDetailsViewModel = new BranchDetailsViewModel(application);

        Observer<Bank> bankObserver = new Observer<Bank>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Bank bank) {
                if(bank!= null)
                    binding.tvBank.setText(bank.getBank());
            }
        };


        branchDetailsViewModel.getBranchById(branchIid).observe(this, new Observer<Branch>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Branch branch) {

                branchDetailsViewModel.getBankById(branch.getBankId()).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), bankObserver);

                branchDetailsViewModel.getCityById(branch.getCityId()).observe(requireActivity(), new Observer<City>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(City city) {
                        if(city != null)
                        binding.tvCity.setText(city.getCity() + " cty");
                    }
                });

                branchDetailsViewModel.getDistrictById(branch.getDistrictId()).observe(requireActivity(), new Observer<District>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(District district) {
                        if(district != null)
                        binding.tvDistrict.setText(district.getDistrict());
                    }
                });

                branchDetailsViewModel.getStateById(branch.getStateId()).observe(requireActivity(), new Observer<State>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(State state) {
                        if(state!= null)
                        binding.tvState.setText(state.getState());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

I tried it both using named and anonymous Observers. I can't understand what is the problem here.

Sometimes it thorow NullPointerExceptions. Sometimes Failed to change locale.

```
04-09 15:48:45.182 2096-2113/com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails/databases/bank_details.db'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Failed to change locale for db '/data/data/com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails/databases/bank_details.db' to 'en_IN'.
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setLocaleFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:386)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:218)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:804)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:92)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:53)
        at androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.java:90)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:476)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:281)
        at com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails.Daos.HistoryDao_Impl.insert(HistoryDao_Impl.java:45)
        at com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails.Repositories.HistoryRepository$1.run(HistoryRepository.java:37)
        at androidx.room.TransactionExecutor$1.run(TransactionExecutor.java:45)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 1802)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:548)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setLocaleFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:364)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:218) 
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193) 
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463) 
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185) 
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177) 
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804) 
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789) 
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694) 
        at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:804) 
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221) 
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224) 
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164) 
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:92) 
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:53) 
        at androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.java:90) 
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:476) 
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:281) 
        at com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails.Daos.HistoryDao_Impl.insert(HistoryDao_Impl.java:45) 
        at com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails.Repositories.HistoryRepository$1.run(HistoryRepository.java:37) 
        at androidx.room.TransactionExecutor$1.run(TransactionExecutor.java:45) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

One more issue is that I am unsure which one I should use in Fragment as Observer's owner, `requireActivity()` or `getActivity()`(I get warning that this could return null, so I haven't used it) or `getViewLifecycleOwner()` (to get fragment's life cycle owner object).

Comment: Which is the real issue? If you put Breakpoints at each "onChanged()" methods, does it been triggered? Or you see that something is not working just by looking at your User Interface (binding.tvCity, binding.tvState, etc...)?

Comment: Actually I figure out the solution by creating custom POJO and running long query in sql to send all data at once. Still the main issue in this question is that how can I assure that all those inner observers not run until parent observer not return something. (I am sure you know that for the first time they return null always). How can we chain Observers so that one run after other fetched value. This question is still quite relevant for me .

Comment: It doesn't answer to my questions ;) I used many times nested "observe()" calls without any issue. In your case there are LiveData, LifecycleOwner and ViewModel which can be the problem. So if you put Breakpoints at each "onChanged()" level then you could understand the real workflow. Additionally: we cannot see any "LiveData.postValue()", so it's more difficult to help you.

Comment: I followed Android Architecture. I also heard that RxJava is quite good. Actually the app is simple and I don't want to add third party libraries. I used prepopulated database created from assets. There is almost 0 inserts. I also searched if there is any READ-ONLY database access is possible using Room, but found nothing. Personally I belive SqliteHelper is better than ROOM.

Comment: If you understand Android Architecture Components and ROOM library, I request you to look at one of my another problem, if you have enough time. I solved this one luckily thanks to sql joins but solving that one is tricky. It giving me FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT error for unknown reason. It is also part of same project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66965010/why-i-am-facing-threading-issues-despite-using-room-database-transactionexecutor/66966137#66966137

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the issue was that I haven't fetched AppDatabase inside `synchronized` block.

Inside AppDatabse class, I changed `newInsance` method from:

```
public static AppDatabase getInstance(final Context context) {
    dbInstance = buildDatabaseInstance(context);
    return dbInstance;
}
```

to

```
public static AppDatabase getInstance(final Context context) {
    if (dbInstance == null)
        synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
            if (dbInstance == null)
                dbInstance = buildDatabaseInstance(context);
         }
//  dbInstance = buildDatabaseInstance(context);
    return dbInstance;
}
```

Now all observers running smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside a Fragment, you cannot pass `this` to observe, you should be passing `viewlifecycleOwner`. In your case you are setting an observe to get the value of branch from room, and then depending on the branch, your other observers are getting called.

This means that your inside observers will observe after your `branch` observer has been invoked.

When you bind your observers to the lifecycle of the fragment, the observers work in accordance with the lifecycle of the fragment itself.

Binding it with lifecycleowner should work, mainly because `this` does not work in case of fragment.

Comment: Ok, so I changed `this` with `getViewLifecycleOwner();`, still the result is same. Interestingly all String results are coming without any errors. But when I create multiple another observers to search city/state/district by id it always return null. Contradictly if I search only one of them result always come right.

I checked multiple times. My sql is corrent. Snippet from CItyDao:`@Query("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE _id = :id")        LiveData<City> getCityById(int id);`

Comment: I think there is some issue with multithreading here. But I am following Android Architecture Components. Not doing anything manually.

Comment: wherever I setup one among the 3 inner observers the result always come right. But when I use 2+ inner observers, all of them return null

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `viewlifecycleOwner` and `this` are accepted. With the inner you must call `YourFragmnent.this`

I see you don't call any function to update the inner LiveData value.
And you shouldn't wrap nested observer because the inner observer will be called several times correspond with the number of the outer observer is called.

You only need to call the function that update LiveData value to trigger onChanged callback of inner observers

Please read this article to avoid consuming data multiple times https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150

Comment: I am just fetching data from pepopulated database. I am not going to insert anything in the database. I searched for read only database access, like we do with SqliteHelper, but found no such thing in Room Libraray.

Comment: @gpl, As I read your code, I assume you want to get Bank, City, District, and State by branch's ID, right?
If so, you can create queries to get those things by branch's ID.
You can see how to create query here  [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query)

Comment: read my comments, I figure out solution by creating a customized Branch POJO to return all data in single query. But I still not know how to make chained observers in Room. This is what I was doing above. I was fetching Branch using branchId, which contains bankId, cityId, districtId. These Ids I use in inner observers to fetch their respective data and show result on screen. Thus I need hierarchical observers. Inner observers need to run only when outer observer return Branch object.

Comment: While debugging they get time to return Branch object. But while Run, Branch return as null and exception arise for inner observers. Thus I am thinking there is some threading issue also. In simple I need full proof solution to create chained observers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please use `YouFragmentClassName.this` or [`viewLifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getViewLifecycleOwner())
2. Add logs to check your `onChange` callback received or not.
3. If you are still getting null values then check your `viewModel` code.

Comment: Is Observer Chaining right? If it is, them what is the problem with my outer-inner observer combination?

Comment: is your first child observer is working (branch / bankObserver) ?

Comment: they work in debug only (because app runs slow that time). When I run it it get crashed. But it not means outer observer return null always. When we comment out inner observers, rest of the code which sets branch object details works fine. I think it is some multithreading issue.

Comment: is that crashing because of null pointer error ?

Comment: I figured out that was happening because I havn't returning `AppDatabse` instance inside `synchronized` block After adding `synchronized` block problem solved.