# Why I am facing threading issues despite using room database TransactionExecutor?

Tags: android, android-room

I have 2 fragments. One is showing Branch Details, other is showing showing branches viewed in history. I want to add entry whenver user see branch details.

I am following Android Architecture principles and using Room+LiveData+Repository+Viewmodel.

Here is BranchDetailsFragment:

```
public class BranchDetailsFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final Application application;
    private final int branchIid;

    private FragBranchDetailsBinding binding;//view-binding

    public BranchDetailsFragment(Application application, int branchIid) {
        //saving branchId
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //normal stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        BranchDetailsViewModel branchDetailsViewModel = new BranchDetailsViewModel(application);
        
        //inserting entry in history table
        HistoryViewModel historyViewModel = new HistoryViewModel(application);
        History history = new History();
        history.setBranchId(branchIid);
        historyViewModel.insert(history);
        
        //fetching data from branches table
        branchDetailsViewModel.getBranchCustomizedById(branchIid).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<BranchCustomized>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(BranchCustomized branchCustomized) {
                //get branch details and show them
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the Branch POJO Room Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "branches")
public class Branch {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "bank_id")
    private int bankId;
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getBankId() {
        return bankId;
    }

    public void setBankId(int bankId) {
        this.bankId = bankId;
    }

}
```

Here is History POJO Room Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "history", foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Branch.class, parentColumns = "_id", childColumns = "branch_id"))
public class History {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "branch_id")
    private int branchId;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getBranchId() {
        return branchId;
    }

    public void setBranchId(int branchId) {
        this.branchId = branchId;
    }
}
```

Here is historyViewModel

```
public class HistoryViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    final HistoryRepository repository;

    public HistoryViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new HistoryRepository(application);
    }

    public LiveData<List<HistoryCustomized>> getAll(){
        return repository.getAll();
    }

    public LiveData<List<HistoryCustomized>>  searchHistoryByBankOrBranch(String token){
        return repository.searchHistoryByBankOrBranch(token);
    }

    public void insert(History history){
        repository.insert(history);
    }
}
```

Here is HistoryRepository

```
public class HistoryRepository {
    private final HistoryDao dao;
    AppDatabase db;


    public HistoryRepository(Application application) {
        db = AppDatabase.getInstance(application);
        dao = db.getHistoryDao();
    }

    public LiveData<List<HistoryCustomized>> getAll() {
        return dao.getAll();
    }

    public LiveData<List<HistoryCustomized>> searchHistoryByBankOrBranch(String token) {
        return dao.searchHistoryByBankOrBranch(token);
    }

    public void insert(History history){
        try {
            db.getTransactionExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dao.insert(history);
                }
            });
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is HistoryDao

```
@Dao
public interface HistoryDao {
    @Query("select history.branch_id, bank, branch from history\n" +
            "join branches on branches._id=history.branch_id\n" +
            "join banks on banks._id=branches.bank_id")
    LiveData<List<HistoryCustomized>> getAll();

    @Query("select history.branch_id, bank, branch from history\n" +
            "join branches on branches._id=history.branch_id\n" +
            "join banks on banks._id=branches.bank_id\n" +
            "where bank like :token or branch like :token")
    LiveData<List<HistoryCustomized>> searchHistoryByBankOrBranch(String token);

    @Transaction
    @Insert
    void insert(History history);
}
```

I know there is some problem with threading because whenever I run this in emulator (BranchFragment), it crash quickly, but when I debug it, it show proper data, though not insert entry in history table. Room has many threading issues.

Here is AppDatabase:

```
@Database(entities = {Branch.class, History.class},
        version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract BranchesDao getBranchesDao();
    public abstract HistoryDao getHistoryDao();

    public static AppDatabase getInstance(final Context context) {
        dbInstance = buildDatabaseInstance(context);
        return dbInstance;
    }

    private static AppDatabase buildDatabaseInstance(Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                AppDatabase.class,
                "branch.db")
                .createFromAsset("branch.db")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build();
    }

    public static void cleanUp() {
        dbInstance = null;
    }

}
```

Here is HistoryDao_Impl(autogenerated by Room library):

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "deprecation"})
public final class HistoryDao_Impl implements HistoryDao {
  private final RoomDatabase __db;

  private final EntityInsertionAdapter<History> __insertionAdapterOfHistory;

  public HistoryDao_Impl(RoomDatabase __db) {
    this.__db = __db;
    this.__insertionAdapterOfHistory = new EntityInsertionAdapter<History>(__db) {
      @Override
      public String createQuery() {
        return "INSERT OR ABORT INTO `history` (`_id`,`branch_id`) VALUES (nullif(?, 0),?)";
      }

      @Override
      public void bind(SupportSQLiteStatement stmt, History value) {
        stmt.bindLong(1, value.getId());
        stmt.bindLong(2, value.getBranchId());
      }
    };
  }

  @Override
  public void insert(final History history) {
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    __db.beginTransaction();
    try {
      __insertionAdapterOfHistory.insert(history);
      __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
      __db.endTransaction();
    }
  }
  
      @Override
      protected void finalize() {
        _statement.release();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here is image showing underline sql:
[image]

Here are the error logs (but it not happen when I debug):

```
04-06 13:58:35.080 2471-2471/com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonHelper.createBackground
04-06 13:58:35.080 2471-2471/com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonHelper.setRippleColor
04-06 13:58:35.090 2471-2471/com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.material.chip.Chip$2', referenced from method com.google.android.material.chip.Chip.initOutlineProvider
04-06 13:58:35.090 2471-2471/com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method com.google.android.material.chip.Chip.updateFrameworkRippleBackground
04-06 13:58:35.100 2471-2471/com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method com.google.android.material.chip.ChipDrawable.updateFrameworkCloseIconRipple
04-06 13:58:35.770 2471-2498/com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_2
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint failed (code 19)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeInsert(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:51)
        at androidx.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insert(EntityInsertionAdapter.java:64)
        at com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails.Daos.HistoryDao_Impl.insert(HistoryDao_Impl.java:48)
        at com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails.Repositories.HistoryRepository$1.run(HistoryRepository.java:41)
        at androidx.room.TransactionExecutor$1.run(TransactionExecutor.java:45)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-06 13:58:39.170 1395-1481/system_process E/ThrottleService: problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Sometimes It throw this error:

```
--------- beginning of crash
2021-04-07 17:05:06.152 4247-4279/com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_2
    Process: com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails, PID: 4247
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032 SQLITE_READONLY_DBMOVED)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForString(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:655)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:336)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:298)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:217)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:195)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:503)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:204)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:196)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:880)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:865)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:739)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:729)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:355)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:92)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:53)
        at androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.java:90)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:476)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:281)
        at com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails.Daos.HistoryDao_Impl.insert(HistoryDao_Impl.java:45)
        at com.appsbharti.bharatbankdetails.Repositories.HistoryRepository$1.run(HistoryRepository.java:37)
        at androidx.room.TransactionExecutor$1.run(TransactionExecutor.java:45)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I have added android_metadata table manually when I throws error of can't fine locale en_US.

```
CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" (
    "locale"    TEXT
);
```

and added `en_US` entry to locale column.

Comment: Add the crash logs with question

Comment: It shows it has Foreign Key Constraint Problem but I checked multiple times there is no such error. Database is created using SqliteStudio and SqlBrowser. They running same quries without any error.
For eg. I modified the query auto-genrated by Room library (add 0 in place of first ? inside nullif()) and run it into those apps and they running it fine. First parameter of History object always remain 0 as id is a global integer variable.

Comment: I have added Branch too, you can compare both History and Branch entities.

Comment: I added this trigger to the history table in case if the inserted branch_id is already present, it deletes old entry before inserting, in that way maintain order and shows recently viewed branch on top.
`CREATE TRIGGER trig BEFORE INSERT ON history WHEN (SELECT branch_id FROM history WHERE branch_id = new.branch_id) IS NOT NULL  BEGIN DELETE FROM history WHERE branch_id = new.branch_id; END`. I dont think this trigger is causing any problem. I also not understand how to add this trigger in room while using prepopulated databse. I just added it using SqliteStudio.

Comment: I checked even after removing that trigger I am getting same foreign key constraint failed (code 19) error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK there was a simple issue behind those all errors. I haven't fetched AppDatabase inside `synchronized` block.

Inside AppDatabse class, I changed `newInsance` method from:

```
public static AppDatabase getInstance(final Context context) {
    dbInstance = buildDatabaseInstance(context);
    return dbInstance;
}
```

to

```
public static AppDatabase getInstance(final Context context) {
    if (dbInstance == null)
        synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
            if (dbInstance == null)
                dbInstance = buildDatabaseInstance(context);
         }
//  dbInstance = buildDatabaseInstance(context);
    return dbInstance;
}
```

Problem is that, Room implicitly call `getReadableDatabase()` not `getWritableDatabse()` of `SqliteOpenHelper`class while fetching query results.

To fetched BranchDetails, I created AppDatabase instance with read-only access inside BranchDetailsRepository.

I fetched same read-only instance inside HistoryRepository(as AppDatbase follows Singleton patter).

So when I called `insert(History history)`, it throws error.

There was no issue of Foreign Key.

Trigger which I created using SqliteStudio also working fine without any problem, no issue with that either.